# Assigning a variable value as json and passing it in request body via postman to springboot controller

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

can we pass a json in a field value in request body via postman and then parse it as a string once we receive it in controller.

Let's say I have class with has a field named input of JSONObject and it takes a json

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can pass JSON value in Request Body